# How to calculate the width of the Windows CMD shell in pixels?

Tags: python, linux, shell, cmd

I'm working on a Python shell script that is supposed to fill a percentage of the user's screen. The shell's width, however, is calculated in characters instead of pixels, and I find it difficult to compare them to the screen resolution (which is obviously in pixels).

**How can I effectively calculate the width in characters with only the screen pixels while still being able to support both Windows and Linux?**

For the sake of the question, let's assume none of the users have changed their shell settings from the default ones.

Answer (score 0):

You cant but the default command prompt dimensions are 677, 343. The height being 677 and the width being 343, hope this helps.